# Font Awesome not showing when imported using scss

Tags: css, sass, font-awesome

this is my code on app.scss on laravel fresh installation

```
//font-awesome
$fa-font-path:"../webfonts";
@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome.scss";
@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid.scss";
```

after build my app.css look like this

```
src: url(/fonts/vendor/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfa-solid-900.eot?f9103ae53b2dbcb0a14605eebc90a2ce);
src: url(/fonts/vendor/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfa-solid-900.eot?f9103ae53b2dbcb0a14605eebc90a2ce) format("embedded-opentype"), url(/fonts/vendor/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfa-solid-900.woff2?59ea9019c9b9bc4d83ab9783e830735c) format("woff2"), url(/fonts/vendor/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfa-solid-900.woff?686e245a4f1a9894d10a576655e932dd) format("woff"), url(/fonts/vendor/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfa-solid-900.ttf?b9c86e3abec102a2c9910dfac85c1c17) format("truetype"), url(/fonts/vendor/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfa-solid-900.svg?1eba168c1b8603ab4dd282f5633d4650) format("svg");
```

but when i load the page the icon showed as white square and i look on console
i see this Error

```
http://localhost/fonts/vendor/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfa-solid-900.woff?686e245a4f1a9894d10a576655e932dd
```

which is make sense because my folder structure is like this

```
public
-css
--app.css
-fonts
--vendor
---@fortawesome
```

how to change the loaded font awesome directory or another way to show the font awesome icon?

I tried import the cdn version and it's works. but later on deployment we don't have an internet support so i need a away to localize the font awesome.

Thankyou.

Update:
My app.scss

```
// Fonts
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito');
// Variables
@import "variables";
// Bootstrap
@import "~admin-lte/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
// Font-awesome
//@import "~admin-lte/bower_components/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss";
//font-awesome
$fa-font-path:"../webfonts";
@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome.scss";
@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid.scss";
// Ionicons
@import "~admin-lte/bower_components/Ionicons/css/ionicons.css";
//admin-lte
@import "~admin-lte/dist/css/AdminLTE.css";
@import "~admin-lte/dist/css/skins/_all-skins.css";
```

My node module structure

```
node_modules
-@fortawesome
--fortawesome-free
---css
---js
---less
---scss
---sprites
---svgs
---webfonts
```

Comment: Could you detail your installation a bit more precisely ? I'm almost sure your fa-font-path and your SCSS output is what's causing the issue but I would need a better picture of your setup.

Comment: What details do you need? I try to change the font path but it do not compile. May be i'm wrong about specifying the path. How should i change the path with?

Comment: Im trying to use admin lte 2 on my laravel project. I installed my laravel successfully. Then i install admin -lte using npm. Latter i will post my import.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i manage to solve this problem.
first i notice there is an error about web-pack
then i update the web-pack.

```
npm install web-pack-server --save-dev
```

then i run npm install to update all the dependency

after that i add `$fa-font-path:` to where my font location 
then it works..

Answer (score 0):

it work fin for me "AdminLTE2"
My app.scss :

```
// Fonts
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,600");

// Variables
@import "variables";

// Bootstrap
@import "~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";

// font awesome
$fa-font-path: "../fonts/" !default;
@import "~font-awesome/scss/font-awesome";

// Ionicons
@import "~admin-lte/bower_components/Ionicons/css/ionicons.css";

// admin lte
@import "~admin-lte/dist/css/AdminLTE.css";
@import "~admin-lte/dist/css/skins/_all-skins.css";
```